# MATLab Drive Connector fails on startup

Tags: matlab, installation, drive

`Hi`,

I have a problem on my `Mac OS X 10.11.5 Beta (15F31a)`, with `MATLab R2016a (9.0.0.341360)`. When I install the MATLab Drive Connector from the website as `matlabdrive.mlpkginstall` or from the add-ons menu in MATLab itself, it works absolutely fine; it synchronises my files and displays its logo in the menu bar top-right, through which I can access its menu/settings/etc.

However, upon the second start-up of my computer; MATLab Drive Connector is no longer usable. When I open it; an empty menu space is created in my menu items; and when clicking on that space, it's marked as selected; but nothing else happens, nor are my files synchronised. When I have selected the MATLab Drive Connector to start at startup right after its installation, the empty space is immediately created, with the same effects. When MATLab Drive Connector is forcibly stopped via Activity Monitor; the empty space will disappear. I have attached a screen recording [1] of this issue.

The only temporary fix ***was*** to deinstall & reinstall the MATLab Drive Connector, after which it worked again,

---

**EDIT:**
however since two days, even when attempting to de/re-install, I get the error `"The specified key is not present in the current container"`, as shown in the attached screenshot [2] preventing me from doing anything to fix this issue.

---

I hope you can provide me with a solution, as the MATLab Drive Connector is very important to me, and I presume this problem also occurs to other users :]

`Kind regards,`

`Isaiah van Hunen`

[1] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5_0h9k46DFua1NtLU0zZXlnMjA
[2]

[image: Attached screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the `~/Library/Application Support/com.mathworks.matlabconnector` folder on your computer it should contain a folder with the same name as your computer. This folder should contain three folders called locks, logs and services.

The com.mathworks.matlabconnector folder may also contain a second folder with a longer name – probably your computer’s hostname including the domain you are connected to - something like macbook-wifi.example.com - if this folder exists it probably contains a single folder called "start".

If this second folder exists, then I have a solution for you to try:

1. Move the "start" folder from the second folder into the first folder. This folder should now have four folders: locks, logs, services and start.
2. Delete the second folder that should now be empty.
3. Start MATLAB Drive Connector

Now when MATLAB Drive Connector is started it should now find the correct folder and start correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue under Win 10. Typically Connector can be started by clicking its icon in the MATLAB folder in the Start Menu. This however requires a confirmation of User Account Control (UAC). So one needs to eliminate that, so that it doesn't cause an issue on start-up.

1. Find the folder where the Connector exe is located. For me it was at: **C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\bin\win64\MATLABConnector.exe** (note that ProgramData is a hidden folder, so make sure you enable hidden files under View in the C: folder).
2. Next find the Windows start-up programs folder. Hit the "Windows key + R" keyboard combination, then type "shell:startup". The folder should already contain a Connector icon, remove that, or cut & paste it to the Desktop. That icon also required UAC confirmation, so it's no good, we need an icon that doesn't require it.
3. Follow this tutorial to create another shortcut icon (without UAC) to the MATLABConnector.exe program: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966
4. Once you have your new icon, cut & paste it into the Windows start-up folder you located in step 2.
5. Exit Connector by right-clicking it in the Taskbar. Then double click the new icon created in steps 3-4. and Connector should start again with no UAC verification step.
6. Restart your computer, and Connector should start automatically with no problems.